# JQuery Slider; How to change button name? (Eg; 'Open', 'Close')

Tags: jquery

**Live View:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/Replaced-With-Divs.html

---

**JQuery Code to Slide & Tab Switcher**

```
$(function () {
    $("#tab-3").toggle(function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '978px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '900px' }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft:'670px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '600px' }, 1000);
    });
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#tab-content div.tab-content').last().fadeIn().find('*').show();

    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').click(function() {
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $('#tab-content div').hide();
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        $('#tab-content div' + href).fadeIn().find('*').show();
    });
});
```

---

**Li of the Show/Hide**

```
<li rel="redeye16.png" id="tab-3"> <a href="#">Hide This</a> </li>
```

---

I would like that when you click to hide the side container, the image rel changes to another image (none of the iamge have been made yet) and for the name of 'Hide This' to become 'Show This'. I would also like the JQuery Tab Switcher I have to not show an empty contain, instead to do the same as what it does, changing the class to current, however keeping the content of the tab you were on, and then if you decide to reopen the current switches back.

Thank you for any time spend in answering my questions.

Best Regards,

Tim

**Edit:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#tab-3").toggle(function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '978px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '900px' }, 1000);
        $(this).find('a').text('Open Me');
        // Problem is Below
        $(this).css("background-image","url(http://www.theaa.com/images/insurance/tick-trans.gif) no-repet");
    }, function () {
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft:'670px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '600px' }, 1000);
        $(this).find('a').text('Close Me');
        // Problem is Below
        $(this).css("background-image","url(http://www.ecvet-projects.eu/Admin/images/icons/Red_X.gif) no-repet");
    });
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#tab-content div.tab-content').last().fadeIn().find('*').show();

    $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').click(function() {
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $('#tab-content div').hide();
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        $('#tab-content div' + href).fadeIn().find('*').show();
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

**The Li CSS:**

```
.tab-list li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-image: url(http://www.ecvet-projects.eu/Admin/images/icons/Red_X.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 12px center;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `toggle()` access the link and go from there:

```
$(function(){
    var mapsInfo = $("#Map-Selection-Info"), atwMap = $("#ATWI80C-Map"), tabContent = $("#tab-content div");
    $("#tab-3").toggle(function(){
        mapsInfo.animate({marginLeft: "978px"}, 1000, function(){
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://www.theaa.com/images/insurance/tick-trans.gif)").find("a").text("Open Me");
        });
        atwMap.animate({width: "900px"}, 1000);
    }, function(){
        mapsInfo.animate({marginLeft: "670px"}, 1000, function(){
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://www.ecvet-projects.eu/Admin/images/icons/Red_X.gif)").find("a").text("Close Me");
        });
        atwMap.animate({width: "600px"}, 1000);
    });
    tabContent.hide();
    $("#tab-content div.tab-content").first().fadeIn().find('*').show();
    $("#Info-Side-Tabs li").on("click", function(){
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $("#Info-Side-Tabs li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        tabContent.hide();
        $("#tab-content div" + href).fadeIn().find("*").show();
    });
});
```

In order to fix that, throw this in your CSS file:

```
#tabs-3 {
    /* other styling... */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 15% 10%;
}
```

And I updated the JavaScript one last time that uses a callback function on the animation to make everything look pretty.

Comment: That is brilliant! I've not made any images to test yet, but would this work to change the rel going by what you have done? $(this).find('a').rel('open.png');. Also have you any suggestions removing the tab switch just for this tab?

Comment: Once you reach the link, `$(this).find('a')`, just manipulate it like any other jQuery object.

Comment: I am very new to JQuery, I've been looking for snippets and due to previous experience making mIRC bots in the MSL programming language i am gladly identically picking it up alike I originality did with HTML/CSS and MSL.

Comment: To edit the `rel` of the `li` element? Check my answer for an update.

Comment: I was actually mistaken, check my edit for my attempt. I thought for some reason the rel made the images show, I don't know why I thought that, I think it is the time... The live version has also been updated.

Comment: Try removing the "no-repet" from the image call: `$(this).css("background-image","url(http://www.ecvet-projects.eu/Admin/images/icons/Red_X.gif)");`

Comment: I've updated the live version so you can see the result to as why I tried to implement the no-repet.

Comment: Fixed. Check my new answer.